# How to get details of the event that triggered a task

Tags: windows, task-scheduler, eventviewer

A service that we are using writes to the event log when issues occur. I have successfully created a task from the event source and id to run a program that notifies the admins. So far, so good.

Unfortunately, the event source and id are always identical for different types of issues. The only way to tell the issues apart is to analyse the error message in the event data text.

Is there a way to pass the event data of the triggering event to the program that is run by the task?